# html5 canvas color switching and line weight

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Basically I have this: http://jsfiddle.net/Alquh/pss3a6jd/

The drawing works great but I am trying to get different tools added like change line weight and line color,(i cant figure out how to get these to work) eventually I want the ability to place boxes, big X's and straight lines too.

EDIT: When I select a different color or line weight it doesn't change, need help.

```
var DrawingCommands = {LINE_TO:       "lineTo",
                   MOVE_TO:       "moveTo",
                   SET_THICKNESS: "setThickness",
                   SET_COLOR:     "setColor"};
```

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? It's not really clear what your actual question is from the current position.

Comment: It's a good idea to include the relevant code **directly** in the question as well as in your jsfiddle

Comment: I guess that's where I'm having an issue, I don't know which code it is. I got this code from a tutorial and I can't figure it out

Comment: You need to read through the JavaScript and try to understand what it's doing then. How new are you to JS?

Comment: As the code stands, it's convoluted and not easy for anyone to understand. I suggest you try rewriting the lot from scratch using your own knowledge. That way you know what does what.

Comment: Been trying to learn for about a week now. The code I have is commented very well..

Comment: Put it another way: it was hard for me to understand and I have 7 years experience.

Comment: I'm about to go and make a basic starting point for you to use, which I'll post here in a while.

Answer (score 1):

Well for not working thickness and color try to change some of those variables to something more accurate:

```
/* Drawing on Paint App */
tmp_ctx.lineWidth = 5;
tmp_ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
tmp_ctx.lineCap = 'round';
tmp_ctx.strokeStyle = '#0052CC';
tmp_ctx.fillStyle = '#0052CC';
```

And about different shapes, i suggest this:
For every shape add array with key values like start and end position for X shape.
If user onMouseDown save first position and in drawning function draw new shape for saved first position and mouse current (to see how shape looks like at the moment) and onMouseUp add first position from mouse down and second from mouse up and add this to array of drawning objects (like ppts in your example).

**Update - more explanation about thcickness:**
I will discuss only thickness and i didn't read whole code, so be aware of that, but it works in relative what you said in your question. Please study carefuly code from you tutorial to know what it is really hapening under the hood.

First of all on the bottom of the page you can find function called *registerInputListeners* but it isn't called anywhere. Changing thickness selection triggers *thicknessSelectListener* which changes *localLineThickness* and this may be variable on which you can rely. Init it in the top of your code

```
var localLineThickness = 5;
```

Now you should set lineWidth before paint. You can do it in the *mousedown* listener.

As far as i've readen your code, i assume that in the end it should be controlled by different remote users, so my solution is not relevant anymore.

Comment: I don't know what those variables should be, the tutorial I got them from worked, but my code isnt...